# Can I avoid using Javascript to achieve this background effect?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have two images: `A (700x1500px)` and `B (700x100px)`. I set A to be the background image for my page. I would like B to also be sort of a background image, but it draws overtop of A.

B cannot be placed at Y < 300px on the page, so if you're at the top of the page, B may not appear on the screen at all. However, if you're at Y >= 300px of the page, B will appear, and be stickied to the bottom of the browser window. Here is an illustration: the blue box is `A` and the red box is `B`, the green line shows the `300px` mark.

[image]

This can be achieved with Javascript, but **can it be done using CSS** and ordinary HTML markup?

Comment: You want the red box to be floating over the page with a fixed position, and only if the page scrollY is over 300px? You should definitely use JavaScript for this.

Comment: @Broxzier This isn't the usual case; it's not a division; it's not a "toolbar". It's a piece of the background-image. I'm actually not permitted to use Javascript for this (though I could; since doing this with JavaScript is quite easy).

Comment: I'm not sure you can. How about dividing the container element when top container is 300px which doesn't have any background and play with fixed position on the 2nd element? not sure if that's possible, just popped into my head :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, and your page has a min-height of 300px, you should be able to use one of the many css sticky footer techniques for this sort of effect.

Like so: http://cleanstickyfooter.herokuapp.com/
or: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
or: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

**OR**, for strictly background image that text will flow over:

Did you try using a fixed position div for the floating image?  Give it a height of 100%, min-height of 300px+height of image, and set a Background image for that div with its position on the bottom.  something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/s_Oaten/JZhsw/

```
#fixedBG {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    background: url(path_to_image) bottom left repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the "sticky footer" not interfere with the layout of page content? The page contents have to appear as the same layout as if there were no footer div at the bottom.

Comment: oooh, I see. updated my answer with fiddle. is that more what you're trying to do?